# Trying to set-up AEM installation in my new laptop and its showing File Not Fount exception

Tags: java, java-8, aem, crx

Was trying to set-up my local environment to practice AEM dev concepts and installed the same version of jdk8 and crx 6.5 version.

When I try to instantiate the author jar, it's showing a FILENOTFOUND EXCEPTION.

I tried with different versions of AEM like 11,17 no clue to the problem

Please can somebody help! Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It would help if you indicated which file is not found.

AEM does not support Java 17 yet, so only 8 and 11 are supported.  I would recommend 11, since it's faster.  

If you switch Java versions then you will have to start again from scratch (delete crx-quickstart directory) if you downgrade (say from 11 to 8 or 17 to 11).  It compiles some classes and older versions won't like classes previously compiled under newer versions.

Comment: Is JAVA_HOME setup? Share what errors appear under crx-quickstart/logs

Comment: Please provide the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

Dont try java17 as it is not supported by AEM yet. AEM 6.5 supports java8 and java11.

I am not sure what steps you are following to setup the local environment or why you are getting file not found exception. Below are some steps that are generally used to set up local dev environment for AEM on windows.

1. Set up jdk- Use jdk8 or jdk11. Do the path setting in the environment variable. Use JAVA_HOME as environment variable name. To test if java is properly installed type `java -version` in command prompt and if you get the proper version then java is installed properly.
2. Set up maven - Use maven version 3.3.6 or above. Set the environment variable M2_HOME. Maven internally relies on JAVA_HOME, so that variable is required. To check run the command `mvn -v` in commmand prompt. If a proper version is displayed then maven is installed properly.
3. AEM jar - Keep the AEM jar and the license property file in same folder. Rename the jar to 'aem-author-p4502.jar' for author running on port 4502. If you need publish instance then replace the author with publish and port as 4503.
4. To start AEM - From command prompt run `java -jar aem-author-p4502.jar`. Depending on system configuration it may take few minutes to start.